# Show plain lock-screen when multimedia cover creates text contrast issue android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, accessibility, album-art

Occassionally I'll be listening to or reading media on my phone and the screen will lock.  When this happens, the lock-screen background is the media "cover".  For white or very light media covers, there is very little contrast between the lock screen numbers and the background, rendering the numbers virtually invisible.  In my last android version, I could swipe down from the clock to bring up a lock-screen with a plain black background.  This is not working with Lollipop.  Is there some trick I'm missing, short of forcing a restart on my phone?  (Samsung S4 16GB)